# How can I copy files from a Compaq Deskpro?

Tags: windows-98, data-preservation

I have a Compaq Deskpro EN 6266 Deskpro EN PII 266 Computer, pictured below.

When I try to insert a 4.7 GB optical disk, the PC stops. When I use a 720MB optical disk it says that I don't have permissions to copy files.

Is there a way to copy the files to some external storage medium? The computer does not have an Ethernet port. It only has 5.7GB of data on it (with Windows and all programs) but there are important files on it and I don't want to lose them.

[image: Front view, showing drives]

[image: Rear view, showing ports]

[image: Close up of some of the ports]

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]. It's not quite clear what you're trying to ask - I'll put your question on hold so that it is clear that the question is still being edited. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Also, it looks like you accidentally deleted an image.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't know how I can copy the files to an external source.I wrote that in my post "is there a way to copy the files to some external? I don't see why you put it on hold

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I couldn't put more than 2 because I need reputation so I deleted one

Comment: Questions here should, if at all possible, be as helpful to others as possible. Also, it's better to clean up a question before people start answering it. If you link to the other image I can add it for you.

Comment: How about I have a go at editing the question, then you see if the edit keeps the meaning of the question? If what I write isn't what you meant to ask, then you (or I) could roll-back the edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't connect it to the internet?" Does it fail to load webpages or does it fail to make a connection at all? Do you know if it manages to reach your router?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The last first photo is like the last but with a different angle,wasn't necessary.I can edit it and put the question on top or if you have another idea I will appreciate the effort to edit it.I can't connect to internet because the motherboard doesn't have the port for the internet cable

Comment: So the computer does not connect to the internet... Does it connect to a USB memory stick?

Comment: Also what operating system does it run? It's likely to be one of windows 95, 95 OSR2 or 98. Only windows 98 supports USB out of the box.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 To connect to an usb stick or an usb mouse I need to go to control panel->add new hardware and then select usb device/data traveler.Data treveler asks for drivers and the usb device says that has been installed but I can't see it if I open my computer

Comment: @PeterI Windows 98

Comment: @CiolteAlin This is the same issue that I had with my Windows 98. Exactly. :-/ I'll write up an answer, but you're not going to like it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I thought to take out the hard disk but I don't know what pins it has and I don't have screws for the bolts that are in the back of the case

Comment: @CiolteAlin You could have said that before I began typing! :-) Ok, so you'll be looking for another solution.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Don't delete what you wrote,the hard disk is compatible with modern computers?Now I can see that I can remove the motherboard support because has a single bolt.Those star bolts are hard to pop

Comment: Is that a SCSI connector on the back, on the bottom expansion backplate? To address your question, do you have a null-modem cable and another computer with a serial port?

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't :(

Comment: Could we have a close-up of the three bottom-right connectors at the back?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 looks like are 2x 9pin serial port and ... https://image.prntscr.com/image/wDaJ4sAFRwCnDcAQpErVlQ.png

Comment: @wizzwizz4, that's two serial ports and a parallel port.  I'm more interested in the one on the expansion card in the middle -- it might be a SCSI port.

Comment: @CiolteAlin Could you take a close-up of the block in the middle as well? I thought the 25-pin had a different number of pins - as Mark and Stephen Kitt have suggested you might have a SCSI port which would simplify things if present.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to continue this in chat rather than in comments.  Comments are not for extended chat and might get migrated.

Answer (score 17):

There are three basic ways:

**a) Get a LAN card and set up a workgroup with all drives shared** and access whatever needs to be backed up to your new machine. This is quite dependent on installed software. But chances are good that some NE2000 compatible card driver is already installed. You have to check what I/O bus system is used and buy the apropriate card. As new PCI or ISA cards are getting rare, Ebay should be a good source.

**b) remove the disk(s) and attach them via USB adaptor to a new machine.** With such a setup you may read the drive from next to any modern machine, as USB, as well as drives over USB, are quite standardized. This will also require way less hardware knowledge than putting the old drive into a new machine. If they (and I assume there are multiple drives, as 5.7 wasn't the original disk size) are PATA (also called IDE) drives, a $15 PATA to USB adaptor will do the trick.  For SCSI drives an adaptor might be less common and way more expensive. Adaptec did once have one available, called USBXchange. A Google search might be helpful.

**c) if these are USB connectors, all the way to the left, right beside the audio connector, you might be able to just plug a USB drive there.** I don't remember if Win98 supported USB disks out of the box. Have you tried to plug in a USB stick? Just try it. Preferably one with less than 32GiB and FAT32.

For installing any drivers (or other software), and if you have no other machines with floppies, just use the CD. It should be able to read writeables. Make sure to burn a **CD** not a DVD or Bluray.

This brings us to way #4:

**d) Use some kind of old fashioned file transfer program.** Put whatever program you prefer on a floppy (or CD) and run it on both machines (the old one and some new one), after connecting them via a serial cable. Some USB to serial if your new machine doesn't offer any classic serial port. This would cost about $15 for the USB/serial, and maybe another $10 for a gender changer.

Oh, and there's one more, without the need for any hardware tinkering:

**e) Boot a live Linux from *CD*.** USB will then most likely work and you may use whatever USB stick to transfer your disk data within a short time. Try Knoppix, as it's well known to come up even on really weird machines. There are many other small, directly bootable Linux distributions, but Knoppix is well known for easy handling even if you're not a Linux buff. Just make sure you pick a **CD-based** one.

(The more as I look at this machine, the less it seems like a Retrocomputing case)

Comment: PATA isn't compatible,is this SCSI?https://image.prntscr.com/image/wDaJ4sAFRwCnDcAQpErVlQ.png

Comment: Two different technologies. And that picture just shows two serial and a parallel. Ken Gobers assumption was about the connector in one of the horizontal slots. It's too blurry to see if it's realy an SCSI or something else.

Comment: The pins aren't vertically aligned if this helps and between them is an horizontal piece of metal

Comment: None of these connectors is of any help here. you need to open the machien anyway. Well, unless you find some way to install SLIP and connect it to a SLIP server like on Linux :))

Comment: Are tehse USB connectors, all the way to the left?

Comment: Yes,but I can't install any drivers to use the mouse or the usb stick

Comment: Try different (small) sticks. For driver installation you could always use a CD. Jsut burn whatever you need. CD, not DVD.

Comment: It says that the universal serial bus was installed but I can't see it near the drives

Comment: Win98 first edition didn't have USB mass storage support (so, no thumb drives or external hard drives).

Comment: Can you recommand an Linux branch that will fit?Knoppix is good?

Comment: @CiolteAlin, I recommend [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/)

Comment: Its going to be USB1 only so transfer speeds will be low.  12 Mbit was the theoretical top speed but realistically it would go much slower..

Comment: SystemRescueCD is targeted at the advanced Linux user, while Knoppix offers a more Windows user friendly environmen.

Comment: @Criggie Who cares? For a one time backup task speed isn'T a real concern. With 1MiB/s the whole 5.7 GiB drive is transfered in less than two hours. Sounds like a good timing for a nap.

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to continue this in chat rather than in comments.  Comments are not for extended chat and might get migrated.

Comment: the 700mb cd was corrupted.maybe that's why I couldn't copy files on it ,I put Linux on USB and on CD but I can't find the solution for booting.I press Esc,Delete,F1,F9,F10 but the only things that shows is a black screen with an _ waiting for something.I pressed some keys and then it shows a blue box with a text in it "Insert password" and if I press some keys nothing happens so I shut down the desktop.

Comment: Also looks like a modem port on that machine, so if you can find a phone line, you can transfer the files. Just somewhat slowly.

Comment: @scruss, *somewhat* slowly?  Assuming that's a 56k modem, and given typical transfer rates, you're looking at a minimum of 17 days to transfer the data.

Comment: What's 17 days in the life of a computer that's already 20 years old, @Mark?

Comment: @CiolteAlin Make sure you're using a Linux version that is compatible with the CPU. Anything x86-64/amd64/x64 is completely out; those are much newer than the Pentium II in that system. You need an x86 variant, i686 at the newest (and even i686 might be too new, so i486 may be a safer choice). I'm not sure how newer Linux kernels (or bootloaders, for that matter!) deal with older/unsupported architectures, but they certainly won't boot.

Answer (score 4):

*Most* (but not all) Windows 98 installations come with HyperTerminal, a serial comms program that supports file transfers over [ZMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) or [Kermit](http://www.kermitproject.org/kermit.html#software). With another computer, a USB-Serial adapter and a null modem cable, you can get files across one at a time.

This will be slow - likely maxing out at 115200 bps / ~ 11 KB/s - but may be the least intrusive option. I wouldn't want to risk installing anything on a hard drive of that age.

Answer (score 3):

The optical drive in your computer is probably a CD-ROM reader.  Unless it actually says "Recordable" or "Rewritable" on the front, don't assume that it will be able to record.  It may not handle DVD-ROMs at all.  Check to see if it has the DVD symbol on the front.

Your computer appears to have a SCSI connector, so the simplest method may be to connect an external SCSI drive, format it and copy your files to it.  But finding such a drive might not be so simple nowadays.

It is probably easier to just add an Ethernet adapter to the computer so that you can copy files to another computer over the network.  You will need to open the computer up first to confirm whether your expansion slots are PCI or ISA.  They are probably PCI but you should check.

Comment: Are you sure it is SCSI ? https://image.prntscr.com/image/wDaJ4sAFRwCnDcAQpErVlQ.png

Comment: Pentium II would likely have ISA and PCI slots,

Comment: That "external SCSI" port is most likely parallel.

Comment: I think Ken is referring to the port on the horizontal expansion card about halfway across the back. Not to the thing next to the serial ports.

Comment: Correct, the SCSI port is the one above the USB, audio and keyboard/mouse ports.  It was not uncommon at that time for Compaq to include a SCSI adapter in their enterprise business line of computers.

Comment: If it's SCSI, there's a SCSI2SD adapter: https://youtu.be/nx1mu7TPtE8

Comment: ...And even if the drive is a recorder, do not assume that facilities are installed that allow recording with anything else than mastering software (as opposed to just copying them the normal way). However, the "720MB" in the original question likely IS a CD-R medium...

Comment: It is possible to find Ethernet adapters for external connection (through USB), though there may be a software issue in making them work.   I have a stack of such adapters, sometimes they just plug-and-play.

Comment: If the already-installed OS supports USB Ethernet it probably also supports USB hard disks or flash drives, in which case that would be the simplest option.

Answer (score 3):

I hated that machines. If my memory serves well they need Floppy to get into **BIOS**. But in a nutshell it is a **PC** compatible machine with **ISA** or **PCI** slots so you can even find a network adapter for it (I still got a box of 10MBit of them somewhere). But with modern components I see this approaches:

1. **HDD**

   In case it have **PATA IDE** interface so you can use any **IDE PATA HDD** but be careful about the barriers so do not use too big partitions. if you got any or even use the machines **HDD** directly. For that you need another computer with **PATA** or **USB to PATA**.

   In case you got **MFM** or **SCSI** then you would have hard time to use it. But that is unlikely as the Compaqs I saw at that time all had standard 40pin **IDE PATA**.
2. **LPT/COM**

   If you boot into **MS-DOS** there are utilities used to communicate by **LPT** or **COM** ports. I used it a lot back in the days. Try to find/use:

   ```
   interlnk.exe
   intersvr.exe
   ```

   That is native to **MS-DOS** and you just need to add

   ```
   devicehigh=e:\rescue\dos98\interlnk.exe
   ```

   into `config.sys` to enable to use it.

   Another option is to use [FX.exe](http://www.download.bg/?cls=program&id=24790) It does not need anything it is stand alone app. So on host computer you just run **MS-DOS** and connect by either **COM** or **LPT** cable ... config both sides `FX.exe` and copy what you need. The host computer can do this for example in emulator ... you just need access to real **COM** or **LPT**. In case on your modern computer is no **COM** nor **LPT** ports you can buy **USB to RS232** or **USB to LPT** reductions but some of them would require tweaking the baud rate and bits to work properly.

   Also Windows support networking over **COM** and **LPT** too I think it is even compatible with the `interlnk.exe` you just need a proper cable and add the network manually in windows on both sides.
3. **USB**

   you got **USB** port I think it twas v1.1. There are memory sticks that are compatible with Win9x you just need driver for it. That will be the simplest way to interconnect. You just format the stick with **FAT32** and use as external removable storage :). The problem is to find stick that has Win9x drivers. I got 2 of them somewhere. Your best bet is to find **SD/MMC** card reader for **USB** compatible with Win9X ... yes those still exist and usually got drivers shipped with them. I even have a mini CD with the drivers somewhere. Or scan USB Flash drives manufactors for Win9x drivers and when found just buy such drive.

Comment: I tried to enter in bios with Esc,F1,F9,F10,Delete but just shows an _.If it needs floppy then the solution is to remove the hard.It's very complicated with externals.

Comment: It should be F10 to get into the BIOS on this system (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/841849/Compaq-Deskpro-En-Series.html, p. 2-5). BIOS setup on a floppy was certainly required for some of the earliest Deskpro systems in the 80's, but I suspect it was long gone by the Pentium II era.

Answer (score 2):

I had the misfortune of having to deal with many of these Compaq systems about 15-20 years ago. The hard drive is SCSI, and probably so also is the CD drive. There is a SCSI controller card installed in the bottom expansion slot, as shown by the mini HD-50 pin external connector.

Booting a Compaq Deskpro is incredibly slow, due to the SCSI controller doing a scan for devices on the bus that takes about a minute or so, before it attempts to boot the hard drive.

Your controller most likely looks something like this image from Wikimedia Commons: (from user Nosachevd, cc-by), https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tekram_DC-300B_Fast_SCSI_ISA_controller.jpg

[image: Tekram DC-300B Fast SCSI ISA controller]

SCSI is obsolete since about 2010, but PCI and even PCI-express controllers are still available if you look around on eBay or Amazon. Example Amazon search result:

Adaptec 2248700-R U320 PCI Express X1 1-Channel SCSI Host Bus Adapter, US$49.00, [https://www.amazon.com/Adaptec-2248700-R-Express-1-Channel-Adapter/dp/B000NX3PII](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NX3PII)

With a modern controller like this, you could plug your old SCSI drive into a computer running Windows 7/8/10 and directly access files on the drive.

Though for simplicity's sake, you should avoid any modern SCSI controller that also says "RAID" in the name of it, as these may not recognize the drive.

,

You would need a computer from about 2012 or older which had the large 4-pin Molex power connectors for IDE/SCSI hard drives. Eventually newer systems dropped those in favor of all-SATA style power connectors.

But even this can be worked around for the persistently stubborn, with a "15-pin SATA male to 4-pin female" power adapter, to plug the old drive into a modern SATA-only drive power connector, for about US$5..

[https://www.amazon.com/C2G-Cables-10149-15-Pin-6-Inch/dp/B003AI272I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AI272I)

,

If you know nothing about the complexities of SCSI IDs, termination, etc, the least complicated thing to do would be to use a 68-pin ribbon for the internal connector of the above card, and then a 68 pin to IDC 50 pin SCSI adapter.

If I continue to use Amazon for this example, a "wide" (68-pin) SCSI internal ribbon cable costs about US$10..

- https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=wide+scsi+ribbon

A 68 pin to "IDC 50 pin female" (the old-style large connector) SCSI adapter is another US$10..

- https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=68+IDC+50+scsi+adapter

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to connect the drive to a data transfer system common to two of your computers, the "nuclear" solution is to remove the hard drive and connect it to an external drive controller. This is a *last resort* - the other answers should be used if possible.

1. Disconnect the computer from power and wait for the capacitor to discharge.
2. Unscrew the case of the computer, taking care to remember which screw goes where.
3. *Carefully* disconnect the cable attached to the hard drive from the motherboard.
4. *Carefully* remove the drive from its housing.
5. Identify the interface.

   - Parallel ATA:
     [image: A 40-pin (2 by 20) connector with a ribbon cable attached]
   - Serial ATA:
     [image: 7 pins, a gap, then 15 pins]
6. Purchase or otherwise gain an adapter for this connector.
7. Connect the adapter to a modern computer.
8. Copy the files from the hard drive.

Comment: So it needs an adapter.

Comment: Through this method, yes. There are others.

Comment: A pentium 2 mainboard well-predates SATA.  I'm positive OP will find Parallel ATA / IDE drive.

Comment: @Criggie Or, *possibly*, some SCSI variant (see earlier comments about Compaq sometimes including SCSI HBAs). Certainly not SATA or SAS.